# Turning off embedded databases with Hibernate

Tags: sql, azure, hibernate, h2, vaadin-flow

I have a Vaadin Flow app that accesses an Azure SQL database that keeps shutting down and restarting. Upon further investigation, I discovered that Hibernate is trying to drop and recreate database tables because it is using an H2 embedded database, which I do not want. After reading the documentation, I determined that I can turn this feature off by setting auto-dll to none in either hibernate.cfg.xml or application.properties or application.yml. The problem is that none of these files exist on my local machine, and I can't find them on my cloud drive either. How can I stop Hibernate from dropping and recreating my database tables?

Comment: There should be at least an H2 dependency in the pom.xml somewhere. Remove that and see where the project fails next. Also, how do you connect to the two databases? A JDNI string can also contain the drop and recreate part.

Comment: When I remove the H2 dependency from pom.xml, nothing changes. The app still keeps shutting down and restarting, the same as before. I connect to my database using JDBC. I have no idea how or why it is connecting to the imbedded database, as that was not anything that I wanted.

In the following excerpt, the statement "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ORDER[*] CASCADE" does not occur anywhere in my code.

Comment: Here is an excerpt from the log stream:

2022-07-13T15:49:44.690Z ERROR - Container for bellapos_0_c9e5e5c2 site bellapos is unhealthy, Stopping site.
2022-07-13T15:49:44.691Z INFO  - Stopping site bellapos because it is not healthy.

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table if exists order CASCADE " via JDBC Statement

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ORDER[*] CASCADE "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
drop table if exists order CASCADE  [42001-200]

Comment: How does your pom.xml look like? And why don't you have an application.properties file? How did you crate the application?

Answer (score 0):

The file was located in src/main/resources. It doesn't show up in a Windows search, not even if I search for system files.